# React-Native packages not finding React headers

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I'm currently trying to integrate React-Native into my existing Swift iOS project. I'm using Cocoapods already so I followed the documentation on the topic by adding the following to my Podfile:

```
# React Native
react_native_path = "../node_modules/react-native"
pod "Yoga", :path => "#{react_native_path}/ReactCommon/yoga"
pod "DoubleConversion", :podspec => "#{react_native_path}/third-party-podspecs/DoubleConversion.podspec"
pod "GLog", :podspec => "#{react_native_path}/third-party-podspecs/GLog.podspec"
pod "Folly", :podspec => "#{react_native_path}/third-party-podspecs/Folly.podspec"
pod ‘React’, :path => react_native_path, :subspecs => [
  ‘Core’,
  'CxxBridge',
  'DevSupport',
  ‘RCTImage’,
  ‘RCTNetwork’,
  ‘RCTText’,
  ‘RCTWebSocket’
]
```

This all works well enough and I'm able to build my app both in the simulator as well as on the device and play around with it.

In a second step I wanted to add react-native-navigation. I added the module to package.json, ran npm install and afterwards react-native-link. All these commands finished successfully. Unfortunately when now trying to build the project it can't find any of the React header files while compiling the react-native-navigation dependency. I already tried various combinations of downgrading react-native again, adapting HEADER_SEARCH_PATHs and so on but with no success ...

react-native version: 0.46.1
react version: 16.0.0-alpha.12
react-native-navigation version: 1.1.134

Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I keep getting An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Answer (score 0):

I keep getting this error as well. Tried clearing all caches, build folder, etc. I believe the error is with Pos files, if I reinstall Pods and then try I can often run my app a few times before the error appears again.

Not sure if this helps, but maybe it will get the conversion started.